# How Do I Dynamically Put the Date and Year in the Title of My WordPress Post?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress blog and I'm wondering, is there a way to automatically put the Month and Year that a post was created or updated in the title of the post?

So for example, if my title is "9 Best Whatever" Then the title would show up as "9 Best Whatever (Feb. 2017)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use title filter.

```
function add_date_to_title( $title, $id = null ) {
    global $post;

    //only for post type post
    if($post->post_type){
        $current_date = date('M. Y');
        return $title . " (" . $current_date . ")";
    }

    return $title;

}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_date_to_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the response. That said, I figured it out. 10 Best Whatever %%currentmonth%% %%currentyear%%